# Clipboard access from NUnit-test

Tags: .net, vb.net, nunit, clipboard

Is there a problem accessing the Windows Clipboard from an NUnit test?

I have a VB.NET application which calls `System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.GetText`—it works fine in my normal exe, however there is no return value when running with NUnit console (x86).

The testfixture itself is marked with `RequiresSTA()`.

I use NUnit 2.5.9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the console app running as a Windows service (e.g. under a CI server)?  If so, [this thread](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/31718443/windows-service--clipboard.aspx) suggests that even though you are using STA, the service is most likely denied access to the desktop, which would be necessary for clipboard access.

Two of your options would be to enable desktop access for the service or to mock out the clipboard somehow for your tests.

Comment: Yes you are right - running Nunit from commandline works! It only fails if it is run from the hudson service - but the service runs under the same user...

Comment: @Tobias: Another option would be to apply e.g. the [`Explicit` attribute](http://nunit.org/index.php?p=explicit&r=2.5.9) to the test so that it isn't run with Hudson, but you can still run it manually.  But at this point I'd really start leaning towards mocking out the clipboard.